# Edit Button in UITableViewController when in Popover

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview

I'm displaying a `UITableViewController` inside a popover. Everything works fine. Now I want that little "Edit" Button on the top right to reorder the cells. But unfortunately I can't achieve this.
I have implemented the 2 delegete methods for reordering, and in my tableviewcontroller I call this on viewdidloead

```
[self setEditing:YES];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
```

but for some reason I can't see the navigation bar on top that should display the edit button.
what am I doing wrong?
thx in advance

Comment: is your table view embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: it is not becouse i thought you wouldnt need that just for the edit button. but when i embed a navigation controller, how do i pass my datamodel then from one viewcontroller to the other when a navigation controller is in between?

Comment: you can create your `UITableViewController` in the same way you did it now, embedded it in an `UINavigationController` using `– initWithRootViewController:` and show the navigation controller in the popover

Comment: perfect, I add it as an answer, this way you can check it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create your `UITableViewController` in the same way you did it now, embed it in an `UINavigationController` using `– initWithRootViewController:` and show the navigation controller in the popover